# How do I get a menu on the left hand side of my SharePoint page?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have created a SharePoint site using Office 365 and I am trying to get the menu to show down the left hand side as currently it is along the top of the page. The site layout is set to Seattle but the menu does not show.  Some of the articles I've read talk about clicking on Navigation link in site settings but I cannot see this link.  Not sure if there is something I need to enable.

How can I get this to show?

**Site Settings**

[image: Site Settings]

**Left Hand Side of Page**

[image: Left Hand Side of Page]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could enable publishing feature, you'll see the setting.

Comment: How do you enable publishing feature from the options I have?  Looks like I need site collection options to enable SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure but I don't have them in site settings and can't work out how to enable them.

Comment: site settings->Site collection features->SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure

Comment: I can't see Site Collection Features in the site settings seen in the screen shot above.  How do I get this option on?